# Fetch all categories from database

Tags: categories, database

My Android project needs to fetch the database every day. I have a category structure like:

1. console
2. tablet
3. camera
4. phone
5. laptop
6. other

The structure of the WordPress database is very confusing. I find my categories in table `wp_term` but I can't find a relationship for fetching my categories.

How do I get all categories with class `wpdb` using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

`get_categories` function will return an array of objects, each object a category.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/

**Edit**

And example, as Tim Malone mentioned in the comment there are examples on that page. But here is a simple one for you, that will display your categories in a list.

```
$categories = get_categories();

if($categories) :
echo "<ul>";
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo "<li><a href='".get_category_link( $category )."'>".$category->name."</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
endif;
```

Comment: thanks sir.I don't know how to use this function.It's very good if you give me an example.

Comment: @Naserkhosravi Did you have a look at the page Nath linked to? There are examples on there :)

Comment: @Nath for the purpose of performance, pass the complete term object to `get_category_link()`, it is faster. Also, if a term is not cached, and the id or slug is passed, you make yet another db call to return the term object, which you already have. If the term is cached, the term object needs to be searched for and returned from the term object cache. If you pass the complete term object, all these extra work is cut out because you give the function exactly what it needs

Comment: Thats very interesting. I had only ever looked it up on the codex.wordpress site where it says the function only requires an int. And never looked at the source. But yes now if you look up the function on developer.wordpress it says you can pass an object! I will start doing that now. Thank you.